# Get ImageView from Toolbar

Tags: java, toolbar, android-toolbar

So I have a toolbar and in this toolbar i have an ImageView. I want to be able to access this image view programmatically from my main activity. The reason why i need to access is it because i need to change the image.

I load my toolbar like this:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Inside my toolbar resource i have this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#18181A">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/NeedAccessToThisId" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the ImageView just like any other view in your activity/fragment/...

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```

Comment: Ohhh. Thanx. Didnt realize it was that easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.NeedAccessToThisId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view to find subviews by their id.

```
ImageView yourImage = (ImageView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.NeedAccessToThisId)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have shown you are getting toolBar instance in java, you can find imageView from toolBar

```
ImageView img=(ImageView) toolBar.findViewById(R.id.NeedAccessToThisId);
```

Comment: Ohhh. Thanx. Didnt realize it was that easy.